# Add custom logo to Highchart graphs

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Is it possible to add custom logo/images to the graphs?

I have tried to modify the [credits](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#credits) label, without luck.

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    credits: {
        text: 'remisture.no',
        href: 'http://remisture.no',
        position: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -75,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25
        },
        style: {
            color: 'red',
            backgroundImage: 'url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/3a/Burger_King_Logo.svg/1024px-Burger_King_Logo.svg.png)'
        }
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/remisture/738bnv0b/

Any idea how to approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from their [support forum](http://forum.highcharts.com/post109693.html#p109693), you can use [`Renderer.image`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.image) just as:

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    // your setup

}, function (chart) { // on complete

    chart.renderer
         .image('//image.com/image.png', 100, 100, 30, 30)
         .add();
});
```

your example with your image: http://jsfiddle.net/738bnv0b/3/

Comment: Thank you! That solves the problem with adding images to the charts.
However, now I facing trouble with placing the image since I have dynamic width for the graph :) Is there a re-render callback I can use to reposition the image if the width changes?

Answer (score 0):

Credits label is only a text and generaly a link to the source of the graph data.

Where do you want to put the logo? Because you're able to put it outside the Highcharts element and position it with css.

Something like that: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/738bnv0b/2/)

```
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div style="position:relative;">
    <a style="display: block;" href="http://remisture.no" >
        <img style="position:absolute; top: 0; right: 0; z-index: 1;" width="40" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/3a/Burger_King_Logo.svg/1024px-Burger_King_Logo.svg.png" />
    </a>
    <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Samuel. 

This will work, but not when exporting/printing the charts, as far as I can see?